# Stop Python from overwriting the file with Condor jobs

Tags: python, condor

The python code with I am trying to execute has to write two different variables to a file. I am using Condor to speed up my process, meaning the python code is executed sync. The write function which I have defined is:

```
with open('output.txt', 'a') as results_file:
      results_file.write(str(gc_count) + '\n')
      results_file.write(str(length) + '\n')
results_file.close()
```

But unfortunately, the file somehow keeps overwriting the results. Could someone help me on how I can write variables to a text file with Condor?

Comment: first don't `results_file.close()`, you've already have a context manager. Then, even if append mode, if you're running this code in parallel threads/processes, you need a mutex.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion! Do you know where I could find an example of mutex usage for this?

Comment: multithreading or multiprocessing?

Comment: I'm using THCondor which is multi threaded

Comment: use `threading.Lock()` object in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the file mode is set as *append*, concurrent writes in the file lead to data corruption.

In a multithreaded environment, you could use `threading.Lock` object to protect your write call:

```
import threading
l = threading.Lock()   # l must be a global variable or a member of some class
```

Then when writing, ask permission for the lock, and release it when file is written:

```
l.acquire()
with open('output.txt', 'a') as results_file:
      results_file.write(str(gc_count) + '\n')
      results_file.write(str(length) + '\n')
l.release()
```

(aside: you don't need the last `close` in a file context manager)

Comment: Thank you very much! It's pretty logic now as well and I understand what I did wrong! The logic to the whole multithreaded environment wasn't very clear to me. Much appreciated!